# How to make use of a global variable in rust?

Tags: rust

I have multiple functions how use the same global vector but the compiler gives me an error. Can I make use a global variable in rust? If not, is there another way to fix my code?

```rust
struct ID {
    id: u32
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut ids: Vec<ID> = vec![];

    fn add_id(id: ID) {
        ids.push(id);
    }

    fn pop_id() {
        ids.pop();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead rustc E0434
```

Comment: Could you use a structure?

Comment: The variable `ids` in your code is local to `main()`, not a global variable. You should avoid global variables unless you are really sure you want them and understand the headaches they will cause you. The error message states that `fn` items can't close over local variables – you'd need to use closures instead to do that, e.g. `let pop_id = || ids.pop();`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach My fault, just updated the code example.

Comment: @AlgoQ did you mean `let mut open_trades` ?

Comment: @cornuz Oops didn't chance `open_trades` to `ids`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the error message and it's possible fix by searching the error code in [Rust Compiler error index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0434), Or using the rust compiler(`rustc`) with [`--explain` option.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html?highlight=explain#--explain-provide-a-detailed-explanation-of-an-error-message)

```
rustc --explain E0425
```

Quoting [from documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0434),

> ***E0434***
>
> A variable used inside an inner function comes from a dynamic
> environment.
>
> Erroneous code example:
>
> ```
> fn foo() {
>     let y = 5;
>     fn bar() -> u32 {
>         y // error: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the
>           //        || { ... } closure form instead.
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Inner functions do not have access to their containing environment. To
> fix this error, you can replace the function with a closure:
>
> ```
> fn foo() {
>     let y = 5;
>     let bar = || {
>         y
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> Or replace the captured variable with a constant or a static item:
>
> ```
> fn foo() {
>     static mut X: u32 = 4;
>     const Y: u32 = 5;
>     fn bar() -> u32 {
>         unsafe {
>             X = 3;
>         }
>         Y
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Note- don't use mutable statics unless you absolutely 100% know what you are doing. Use a regular static with something from `std::sync`.